# How to set php array as property value Cypher-Neo4j

Tags: php, cypher, neo4jphp, neo4j

I have a php array `$id=[12344,546674,6789];`

I want to set this array as the value of the property `id` of the relationship `:knows` , represented as

```
(:user)-[:knows{id:[]}]->(:data)
```

I use everyman php plugin for neo4j

I have tried the below query , but it gave an error `Array cannot be converted to string`

```
    $id=[12344,546674,6789];
    $client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client();
    $query= "match (u:user{id:".$user_id."})-[r:knows]->(c:data)
             set r.id=".$id."";
    $result = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $query);
```

Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution,

I am posting this answer to help other people having the same doubt.

Instead of directly specifying the array in the cypher query , you could use it like this

```
$id=[12344,546674,6789];
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client();
$query= "match (u:user{id:".$user_id."})-[r:knows]->(c:data)
         set r.id={myid}";
$result = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $query,array('myid' => $id));
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
set r.id=".$id."";
```

Wrong! You can't convert array to string! It is php error, not neo4j

In cypher arrays are represented as [1,2,3]
Query should looks like

```
 $query= "match (u:user{id:".$user_id."})-[r:knows]->(c:data)
             set r.id=[" . implode(',', $id) . "]";
```

It is even better to use statement params, but i don't know the **exact** syntax. Should be something like:

```
$params = array( 'id' => $id');
$query= "match (u:user{id:".$user_id."})-[r:knows]->(c:data)
             set r.id= {id} ";
    $result = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $query, $params);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have already found the answer, see my answer below